# Cloud9 ide for Django web development

Tags: django, cloud9-ide

I'm developing a web application using Django with a small team. We each have a Django server running on local machines, instead of using traditional repositories to maintain our code I was wondering if Cloud9 would be a better approach. I would love the ability to pair program and comment on each others code similar to google docs. However, I can't seem to find a straight answer for whether or not cloud9 can run a small django server for testing like it does for a node server.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to do this in Cloud9. The downside here is that Cloud9 lacks debugging and has only basic code completion for Python apps at the moment. However, there are a lot of positives as well, as you pointed out in your post.

Anyway, Cloud9 gives you a VM per project which runs Python 2.6.6, so that should be fine.